# How to take 2 different pictures with one click

Tags: android, android-camera, image

[image]

I want to take 2 different pictures with one click. I don't want to take two same images side by side with one click. Is it posiible?

Comment: -1 for "Suggest me some codes." - have you even tried something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the simple answer it is not possible when you have only one single camera lance at side. But then also if you are too much eager to do it then you can create two threads and perform this action, but be careful there are lot of chance that your camera will get damage, battery will drain more and may be your device get hanged.